# How to estimate the uncertainty of a function that has to be solved numerically

Tags: error, error-propagation, chemometrics

Consider I have a function:

$PV_m^3 - PbV_m^2 +aV_m+ab=RT$

In this example I have measured the uncertainties in $P$ and $T$ experimentally and the errors in $a$ and $b$ can be assumed to be zero. How would I go about estimating the error in $V_m$?

Normally, I use the variance route:

$s_a = \sqrt {s_b^2(\partial f/\partial b)^2 + s_c^2(\partial f/\partial c)^2+...}$

where

$a = f(b,c,...)$

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to approach this with $V_m$ as I don't know what $V_m=f(P,T)$ looks like.